# C - Memcpy not working

Tags: c, memcpy

First, know how memcpy work: the third parameter is the number of bytes copied, however, i still have a problem ...

Here's my struct:

```
#define ARRONDI(X, Y) 1 + (X / (Y + 1))
#define Taille ARRONDI(Max_Length, 64)
#define Max_D 7
typedef unsigned long long ull;

typedef struct{
    ull List[Taille];
    ull best_solution[Taille];
    ull Dist[Taille];
    int borne;
    int Length[Max_D-1];
    int nb_mark;
}tache_t;
```

Taille and Max_D are both Macro defined earlier.
When i've 2 tache_t, a and b, and i wanna copy the "best_solution" array from one to another, so i type

```
#include <string.h>
int main(){
int i;

tache_t t;
t.best_solution[0] = 52461701;
t.best_solution[1] = 0;

ull T[Taille];
memcpy(T, t.best_solution, sizeof(ull) * Taille);

for(i=0; i<Taille; i++)
    printf("%Lu vs %Lu\n", T[i], t.best_solution[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

But when i checked values, both array were a bit different ... 
How is it possible ??

I was wondering if it was a padding problem ... but obviously it isnt, right ?

Comment: `both array are a bit different`...clarify `a bit`

Comment: And please show the definition of the `Taille` macro.

Comment: If you are wondering something, verify it instead of assuming it.  Eventually you will wonder less, and eliminate the chance that something is taken on faith is wrong.

Comment: The first ull is correct (both are equal), however, the second is different.
I've 0 in src (which is what i want) and 4204032 in the dest o.o

Comment: Try provide a SMALL but COMPLETE (in the sense that someone else can compile/link/run it) sample of code that exhibits the problem.  You're leaving things out, and the code you are showing would not exhibit the problem.  This means some code you have chosen to omit is the culprit.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific: Is the copy completely different from the source or does it differ from a certain offset on? I still suspect that your `Taille` macro is not resolved as you think it is. Please show its `#define`.

Comment: For constant `Max_Length` equal `64000` your macro `ARRONDI(Max_Length, 64)` calculates a result of `985`. Is that what you intended? If you tried to calculate the length of array of Y-bits-long items to keep X bits then your formula `1 + (X / (Y + 1))` is wrong–it should be `((X+Y-1)/Y)` instead. You should NOT divide by `(Y+1)` if you want to divide by `Y`.

Answer (score 3):

Aha! If you run your code through the preprocessor only (with gcc's  `-E` option), you'll see that the `memcpy` line is resolved as:

```
memcpy(T, b.best_solution, sizeof(ull) * 1 + (Max_Length / (64 + 1)));
```

Macros are textual replacements. In your case, you can guard against erroneaous replacement by putting the whole expression in parentheses:

```
#define ARRONDI(X, Y) (1 + (X / (Y + 1)))
```

If you want your macro to be valid in all circumstances, place parentheses around the arguments, too:

```
#define ARRONDI(X, Y) (1 + ((X) / ((Y) + 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This part of source code:

```
sizeof(ull) * Taille
```

becomes:

```
sizeof(ull) * ARRONDI(Max_Length, 64)
```

after the `Taille` macro expansion, which in turn becomes:

```
sizeof(ull) * 1 + (Max_Length / (64 + 1))
```

after substitution of `ARRONDI`.
Is that what you wanted...?

Comment: Right, you find a mistake ! Thanks for that :)

You're such a god ;)
I just add braces around the definition of "ARRONDI" and its ok .. thanks you so much, 2 days lost for that :'(